# #react-starter-kit React onClick not firing on page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-starter-kit

I'm using the [React-Starter-Kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) and am having an issue with an onClick={this.handleClick} not firing in the browser.

**What is happening:** The Colorswatches.js component is loading and showing up in the browser but the onClick isn't working. No console logs are showing up.

**What I think is the problem:** Rendering everything server side and passing to client, client gets static react html with no event bindings.

**How do I get the click event to work client side after server side rendering?**

**EDIT: Updating code with provided example from jgldev**

**EDIT 2: Added componentDidMount() function. With a console log, still not seeing the log on page load**

**EDIT 3: My issued was with another part of the React-starter-kit that was bombing out the client side re-render. I marked the first answer as correct.**

`src/component/ColorSwatches/ColorSwatches.js:`

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles';
import s from './ColorSwatches.scss';

class ColorSwatches extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('I was mounted');
    }
    handleClick(){
        console.log('I was clicked');
    }
    render(){
        let colorSlices = this.props.colorSlices;
        let sku = this.props.sku;
        let currentSkuIndex = 0

        return (
            <div className='pdpColors'>
                <div className='colorSwatches' >
                    { colorSlices.map((colorSlice, index) => {
                        return (
                            <div title={colorSlice.color} onClick={()=>this.handleClick()}  key={index}>
                                <img src={colorSlice.swatchURL}/>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withStyles(ColorSwatches,s);
```

Comment: `this.handleClick().bind(this)` is incorrect. try `this.handleClick.bind(this)`

Comment: Ah yes, that was a typo. I have it like your example in my code. I will edit post

Comment: you also don't need the extra arrow function in `onClick`, all you need is `onClick={this.handleClick}`. It defeats the purpose of binding the function to the component and will instead create a new function every time it renders

Answer (score -1, accepted):

on the constructor:
`this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)`

Then, in the render function:

`onClick={()=>this.handleClick()}`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, This still doesn't seem to work for me. No console logs firing, nothing.

Comment: maybe the onClick prop is onclick?

Comment: doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: the extra line in the constructor does not seem to make any sense. Your binding issue is inside the render function.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the following is going on:

- Originally, `this` referred to the mounted DOM component, which is not what you want.
- Wrapping the onClick to `onClick={()=>this.handleClick()}` is a step in the right direction, but not enough. `this` now refers to a react component, but not the right one. It is defined inside a `.map` function, so it refers to the `colorSlice`. Which is not what you want.

My advice take it one step further:

inside render, before your return statement, add the following line

```
let that = this; // this refers to ColorSwatches component, as intended
```

and inside the mapping function change onClick to:

```
onClick={that.handleClick}  // no need to add the wrapper now
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: he's using an arrow function which wont create it's own 'this' but instead use 'this' of the component

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this,

first of all make a var that contains this. this should happen in your `render()`

```
var self = this;
```

Then on your onClick

```
onClick={self.handleClick.bind(this)}
```

This worked for me when i ran into this problem.

Hope it works out!